# Adding a (automatic) date field in data entry form using Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: forms, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint data entry Form for my List (Inspection Table), which has a field called "Date Entered". I want to automatically populate today's date and time when a user clicks on "Add new entry", as I want to use that as audit data.

Now, I wanted to use java script (as after research, this seems the most straight forward way to do so), so I added the following to the NewForm.aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date(); 
var dd = today.getDate(); 
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); 
if(dd<10)
{dd='0'+dd;} 
if(mm<10)
{mm='0'+mm;} 
var formattedToday = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
alert(formattedToday);
document.getElementById('<%=  ((TextBox)this.onetIDListForm.FindControl("ff10_1")).ClientID %>').value = formattedToday;
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

The `alert(formattedToday);` is just to test if the java script is picked up of course and will be removed in later stage.

Ok.. I get the popup, so the value is calculated correctly and java script works. The problem I have, is putting this value to the "Date Entered" field.

What would be the correct method to call the document.getElementByID?

I have tried multiple variations:

```
document.getElementById('<%=  ((TextBox)this.onetIDListForm.FindControl("ff10_1")).ClientID %>').value = formattedToday;
```

Or..

```
document.setElementById("Date Entered").value = formattedToday;
```

Or..

```
document.setElementById("ff10_1").value = formattedToday;
```

Can somebody point me to the correct format, or the way to make this work?

Next to the script above, I think I need the Form field "Date Entered" behavior (enable view) to be set to "False" but that is out of scope at the moment.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article.  It talks about how you can achieve this using jQuery.  See sample below and try it out.  You will have replace the column name with your corresponding name "Date Entered".  This should populate the appropriate textbox for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function() {

  $('input[title=DefaultMeFieldNoSpaces]').attr(
       {value: 'You are in a twisty maze of passages, all alike.'});
  });
```